# TableView appears before data loads

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I assign my table view delegate and datasource from `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`, which is called from my `viewDidLoad()` the table view will appear before any data loads in it and a few seconds later the data will appear. If I assign the delegate and datasource outside of the closure there is a slight lag but the tableview appears with all the data loaded. I must assign the tableview's properties in the closure since UIKit is not thread safe. Is there a way to get my data to load before the tableview appears or should I just use an activity indicator for 1/2 second while the cells are populated?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let normalDays = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NormalClasses", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? NormalClassesView, let specialDays = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SpecialClasses", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? SpecialClassesView {
        //I removed some code here for sizing the views since it didn't pertain to the question
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableViews.forEach{
                if let tableView = $0 {
                    let nib = UINib(nibName: "BasicClassInfoCell", bundle: nil)
                    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "periodCell")
                    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
                    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
                    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                    tableView.delegate = self
                    tableView.dataSource = self
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "periodCell", for: indexPath) as? BasicClassTableViewCell {
        cell.backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: _I must assign the tableview's properties in the closure_ - no, you don't, since `viewDidLoad` is called on main thread

Comment: Oh ok, then would you know how to get rid of the lag that occurs while it is loading?

Comment: Not unless you show how you actually load the data

Answer (score 0):

just hide tableView until the load is finished than set hidden as false